# Compacting Number values into shorter string

Tags: python, string, numbers

I have 1296 random values ranging 0-31. I want to represent this information so let’s say I just concatenate all 1296 values into a string. If I were to do that the string would be about 2500 characters long. How can I store this information in a shorter string so I can still know all 1296 values in the correct order but not have such a long string? (I managed to get it to 648, but wanted to see if someone has an even better way)

Comment: Does the order matter? If not: put them in a `Counter`. Should the output be human readable? Alternatively compress the data using whatever algorithm you like.

Comment: Another option is to use a bit-style approach - map each number to ASCII values - for instance.

Comment: Yes it does have to be in order unfortunately

Comment: It takes 5 bits to store a number from 0-31, so a simple approach would be to convert it to bits and store that.  It would end up at 810 bytes.

Comment: I’ve used something similar to get to 650 in length but I was asking to see if anyone had a better idea that could shorten it even more

Comment: The highest number of bits in a unicode character is 17. Your random values only have, at most, 5 bits each. Therefore you can pack 3 of your random numbers into a *chr* which will reduce your string to a length of 432. However, this can only be done reliably if your list of numbers has a length divisible by 3. Otherwise you'd need some kind of padding strategy which would be easy if the random range was 1-31 but as it's 0-31 your list length would have to be divisible by 3

Answer (score 1):

This will work when the range of numbers in the input list are 0-31 (inclusive) **and** when the list length is a multiple of 3

```
import random

numbers = [random.randint(0, 31) for _ in range(1296)]

def pack(n):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(n), 3):
        result.append(n[i] << 10 | n[i+1] << 5 | n[i+2])
    return ''.join(map(chr, result))

def unpack(s):
    result = []
    for o in map(ord, s):
        for shift in 10, 5, 0:
            result.append(o >> shift & 0x1F)
    return result

packed = pack(numbers)
print(len(packed))
result = unpack(packed)
assert result == numbers
```

**Output:**

```
432
```

**Note:**

If the range of numbers was 1-31 then this technique (with a minor modification) could be used for any list length because zero could be used as a padding indicator as follows:

```
import random

numbers = [random.randint(1, 31) for _ in range(1295)]

def pack(n):
    result = []
    a = None
    for i, x in enumerate(n):
        match i % 3:
            case 0:
                a = x << 10
            case 1:
                a |= x << 5
            case _:
                result.append(a|x)
                a = None
    if a is not None:
        result.append(a)
    return ''.join(map(chr, result))

def unpack(s):
    result = []
    for o in map(ord, s):
        for shift in 10, 5, 0:
            if (n := o >> shift & 0x1F) == 0:
                break
            result.append(n)
    return result

packed = pack(numbers)
print(len(packed))
result = unpack(packed)
assert result == numbers
```

Comment: So wait is this making the output 432 characters long? Also what was your method for shortening it even more because I believe I could get rid of the 0

Comment: These are not all legal characters, for example U+D800 through U+DFFF.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk They are not legal in terms of being printable but they can be used in this context. The Unicode code point range is 0 to 0x10FFFF

Comment: @James The method is based on packing 3 values into one Unicode character. Hence 1296/3 == 432. If the input range is 1-31 then you could use zero as a padding value and there would be no reliance on the input length being a multiple of three

Comment: @Stuart this makes sense but I am confused what you mean by padding with zero, what benefit is there from this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store 32 unique values in one character, which means your 1296 numbers can fit in a string of 1296 characters.

For example:

```py
import random

numbers = [random.randint(0, 31) for i in range(1296)]

def numbers_to_string(numbers):
    return "".join(chr(ord("0") + number) for number in numbers)

def numbers_from_string(string):
    return [ord(char) - ord("0") for char in string]

numbers_str = numbers_to_string(numbers)
numbers_roundtrip = numbers_from_string(numbers_str)

print(numbers_roundtrip == numbers)
```

Output:

```
True
```

These are the numbers and the characters used to represent them:

```
 0 0
 1 1
 2 2
 3 3
 4 4
 5 5
 6 6
 7 7
 8 8
 9 9
10 :
11 ;
12 <
13 =
14 >
15 ?
16 @
17 A
18 B
19 C
20 D
21 E
22 F
23 G
24 H
25 I
26 J
27 K
28 L
29 M
30 N
31 O
```

Comment: While this does work, I was hoping for an even shorter string if possible

Comment: Fair enough. Can it be a unicode string? There are apparently 467241 printable characters. That's a lot more to play with than ASCII's 95.

Comment: It could be and I could get it to 432 characters in length. The best solution I’ve thought of so far uses this and another method to get it down to 370-420 but again I thought it was worth checking to see if anyone has a better idea than me

Comment: 370, that's impressive. Can you please include that code in your question, or even as an answer as it outperforms the existing answers.

Comment: This question has come up in various guises before, and usually theres some confusion by the OP about what it means to be a *character*. Are you trying to minimize file storage, or RAM storage, or on-screen real estate?

Comment: On screen realestate

Comment: @GordonAitchJay so all I did was just when there is 3 or more of the same value next to each other I compact it to the number and then the symbol. Because there is only 32 possible values and 1296 spot it is guaranteed to be a few lines of the same value and that is why I said 370-420 because it could be more or less of that just depending on chance